# Plugin's setting template not found

Tags: plugin-development

I have made a simple plugin (with pluginfactory.io) that has been working perfectly so far. But after taking it to our live test-site it is causing the /admin/settings page to stop working, throwing the error that the plugin's settings template cannot be found.

> [error] [exception.Craft\TemplateLoaderException] Craft\TemplateLoaderException: Unable to find the template “pluginname/pluginName_Settings” in "settings/_index" at line 8. in /craft/app/etc/templating/twigextensions/TemplateLoader.php:123

I have dumped the production DB and imported it locally, I have checked that the files exists both in git and on the server, but I still only get this error on the server, everything is working fine locally.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

```
public function getSettingsHtml() {
    return craft()->templates->render('pluginname/pluginName', array(
        'settings' => $this->getSettings()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like production has a case-sensitive file system and locally you don't.

For example, you're trying to render a template called `mytemplate.html` on the file system, but you're using `myTemplate.html` in the plugin code.

Comment: Thank you, this would have taken me ages to figure out on my own!